# Lock the Map view of Map Control in windows phone 8.1

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, dictionary, windows-phone-8.1

I am having a map control in my windows phone 8.1 app. I want to lock the view of the map, ie, user shouldn't be able to zoom or scroll to different view, but the pushpins on the map should be still clickable. Is there any way to do it?

Comment: I have struggled with that same situation a little while ago and there seems to be no optimal solution. The best thing you can get is to define the property `IsHitTestVisible` of the map to false and the draw the pins, not as part of the map, but as independent objects in your layout :S
But I would be glad if anyone else finds a solution. ;)